# WSL-bash-launched Windows apps exclusively lock files

Tags: windows, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) bash to handle git commands on my Visual Studio projects. I have my `difftool` command configured to launch Beyond Compare (Windows program). What I see is Beyond Compare exclusively locks the files it is showing. The file unlocks when Beyond Compare is closed. Beyond Compare used directly from Windows does not lock files.

Repro steps:

1. Set up git config difftool to use Beyond Compare<sup>1</sup>
2. Make an edit to a source file
3. Run difftool (`git difftool &`) to launch Beyond Compare
4. Make another edit to the source file (e.g., using Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code) and attempt to save the file
5. Observe error saving the file

I can make edits in Beyond Compare, but often times prefer to make edits in Visual Studio.

Is there a way / workaround to fix this problem?

I did find this [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config) about `wls.conf` and will try setting up `/etc/wsl.conf` as

`[automount]
enabled=true
options=uid=1000,umask=0022,fmask=0022,dmask=0022`

when I get the Windows build version that supports it (17093 vs my current 16299) in the future. Is there a wsl.conf that would fix my issue?

<sup><sup>1</sup>[difftool "bcomp"]
cmd = \"/mnt/c/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/BComp.exe\" \"$(winpath \"$LOCAL\")\" \"$(winpath \"$REMOTE\")\" /lefttitle=\"$(winpath \"$LOCAL\")\" /righttitle=\"$(winpath \"$REMOTE\")\"</sup>

Comment: I upgraded to Windows 10 v1803 build 17134 and tried several variations of `wsl.conf`, and this file locking problem remains.

Comment: I went back to using `cygwin` and the file lock problems are gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me which is to upgrade to Windows 1903. The 1903 version of WSL uses a [9P protocol file server](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/whats-new-for-wsl-in-windows-10-version-1903/) which solves the problem.

Comment: Note that if you set up a distro _before_ 1903, then either you need to upgrade it (with the `-upgrade` command, as written in the article), or just drop it and set up a completely new distro (which is what I did).

Comment: Well, unfortunately, upgrading to 1903 & having a new distro didn't make the problem go away completely (maybe it became a bit less common, but maybe that's just wishful thinking on my part). So what I do when files get locked now is shutting down my distro with `wsl -t ubuntu` (or `debian` or what have you) from CMD/PowerShell, and restarting it by opening a new bash window. It's still super annyoing, but a bit less so than restarting Windows altogether to get files unlocked.